# Rename Subfolder folder name with File name inside the folder - vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Can someone help me with VBA code to rename the subfolder with the part of file name as given below

Folder : C:\Test

Sub folders : C:\Test\a , C:\Test\b , C:\Test\a .... Goes on

It has some file contents and I have to match a file with name starting with VDX_000674 and get last 4 characters and rename the Folder with that.

I have tried the below code but with no use any edits will be appreciated

```
Sub Rename()
    Call Test_Rename("C:\Users\shanmso\Desktop\VN\Output")
End Sub

Sub Test_Rename(MyPath As String)

    Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objSubFolder As Folder
    Dim objFile As File
    Dim Riname As String

    Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(MyPath)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Left(objFile.Name, 15) = "DEX-VH_00000374" Then
            Riname = Mid(objFile.Name, 17, 3)
            Name objFolder As Riname
            Exit For
        End If

    Next objFile

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Test_Rename MyPath & "\" & objSubFolder.Name
    Next objSubFolder

    Set FileSys = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objSubFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have updated my code ! but its not working as required

Comment: Since you haven't told us anything beyond "it doesn't work", you're not going to get anything better than random guesses. Based on that, I would guess that there's something wrong with this line:`Name objFolder As Riname` since that doesn't look like proper VBA code. If you would like to be more specific on what "It doesn't work" means, you're likely to get better quality answers more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

untested. but I think FreeMan is right `Name objFolder As Riname` should be something more like this `Call MkDir(MyPath & "\" & Riname)`

Also I don't think you need the second `For Each` loop so I removed it. I'm guessing you thought this was actually creating the subfolders, but it isn't. Its easier to just rename the folders in the first For each loop

```
Sub Test_Rename(MyPath As String)

    Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objSubFolder As Folder
    Dim objFile As File
    Dim Riname As String

    Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(MyPath)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Left(objFile.Name, 15) = "DEX-VH_00000374" Then
            Riname = Mid(objFile.Name, 17, 3)

            Call MkDir(MyPath & "\" & Riname)

            Exit For
        End If

    Next objFile

    Set FileSys = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objSubFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing

End Sub
```